# Unable to select text in editor when multiple classes are assigned to a tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

I am using **Bootstrap** classes and would like to have a bootstrap styled
button in my text. When I have text like below in the ckEditor, I
cannot select the word **shortly**. Is this a bug?

`Try this <span class="btn btn-primary">shortly</span>`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. **Bootstrap** class **btn** has style rules like

> -webkit-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;

these rules are causing my problem.